# I can't install packages using yum [Errno 5] [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: linux, redhat, python, yum

I cannot install git package on server. Below is the output of yum command:

```
   [root@sbybz221033 ~]# yum update git
    Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
    Resolving Dependencies
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.8.3.1-21.el7_7 will be updated
    --> Processing Dependency: git = 1.8.3.1-21.el7_7 for package: perl-Git-1.8.3.1-21.el7_7.noarch
    ---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.8.3.1-22.el7_8 will be an update
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package perl-Git.noarch 0:1.8.3.1-21.el7_7 will be updated
    ---> Package perl-Git.noarch 0:1.8.3.1-22.el7_8 will be an update
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution

    Dependencies Resolved

    ============================================================================================================
     Package              Arch               Version                       Repository                      Size
    ============================================================================================================
    Updating:
     git                  x86_64             1.8.3.1-22.el7_8              rhel-7-server-rpms             4.4 M
    Updating for dependencies:
     perl-Git             noarch             1.8.3.1-22.el7_8              rhel-7-server-rpms              56 k

    Transaction Summary
    ============================================================================================================
    Upgrade  1 Package (+1 Dependent package)

    Total download size: 4.4 M
    Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
    Downloading packages:


    Error downloading packages:
      git-1.8.3.1-22.el7_8.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 13] Permission denied
      perl-Git-1.8.3.1-22.el7_8.noarch: [Errno 5] [Errno 13] Permission denied

    [root@sbybz221033 ~]#
```

Comment: It seems that you get a permissions denied error. Try using `sudo yum update git` and provide the output.

Comment: Errno 5 is I/O error, either your volume is full or something bad is happening. Try running `yum clean all && rm -fr /var/cache/yum`, and try `yum update git` again. If you still got I/O error, check your syslog.